# WP Loop Specific Metabox Value From All Post On Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created function for loop specific metabox value from all post on custom post type. It's working perfectly. Here are the codes:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'myposttype', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['custommetabox_mb'];
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
  }

endwhile;
```

Is it possible to just loop some metabox value. Example:

There have 2 metabox on this custom post type.

```
First  = custommetabox_mb
Second = custommetabox_mbb
```

What I want is, just loop `custommetabox_mb` if `custommetabox_mbb` value same with text `"yiedpozi"`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use [meta_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'myposttype', 'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'custommetabox_mb',
            'value' => 'yiedpozi',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'custommetabox_mbb',
            'value' => 'yiedpozi',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),  'posts_per_page' => -1,);

$loop = new WP_Query($args); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['custommetabox_mb'];
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
  }

endwhile;
```

Comment: why the down mark? -- edit: I don't mean the name of the author... I mean the vote.